# add 2 numbers upto 40 digits through operator overloading

Tags: c#

i want to add 2 numbers which are upto 40 digits through operator over loading.

what type of data type or variable i have to use?

how can i make my own data type which is capabale to store a very large number and add them into another variable

```
class Complex
{
    long x;
    long y;
    public Complex(){}

    public Complex(long temp, long temp2)
    {
        x= temp;
        y=temp2;
    }
    public static Complex operator + (Complex c1,Complex c2)
    {
        Complex c3= new Complex();
        c3.x= c1.x+c2.x;
        c3.y= c1.y+c2.y;
        return(c3);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (String.Format("{0} + {1}i", x, y));
    }

}
```

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Complex a, b, c;
        //i wan't add these numbers . . .
        a = new Complex(228743289749287498276,27236784267346287648726872);
        b = new Complex(1234654823648762387468726,242367236487627346872387);
        c=a+b;

        Console.WriteLine ("a= " + a);
        Console.WriteLine("b= " + b);
        Console.WriteLine("c= " + c);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you only need integers? If so, look at `BigInteger`... Note that your title says 20 digits, and your body says 40 digits. Which is it?

Comment: Eh *complex math* task with *integers* of 20+ or event 40+ digits? What's the underlying problem then?

Comment: sorry for this i have edited my question